# Safari not running css display:none property

Tags: html, css, safari

I have the following html:

```
<div id="loadinganimationsearch">
    <div style="color: #28ABE3;font-size: 14px;float: left;">Fetching Textbooks</div>   
    <div id="block_1" class="barlittle"></div>
    <div id="block_2" class="barlittle"></div>
    <div id="block_3" class="barlittle"></div>
    <div id="block_4" class="barlittle"></div>
    <div id="block_5" class="barlittle"></div>
    <br>
</div>
```

This is what the HTML produces:

[image]

Now I have the following CSS, that as the browser runs the `loadinganimationsearch`has no display in chrome and firefox.

```
 #loadinganimationsearch {
     display: none;
}
```

But now when I run it in Safari 5.1.7, it seems to almost ignore the CSS for some reason. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Caching perhaps? I see no reason why it shouldn't work. I know Safari 5.1.7 is buggy, but I do know that `display: none` works in it. Edit: I just tested the code you provided in Safari (Windows) 5.1.7, and it worked..

Comment: Its interesting, I thought Safari wasn't understanding display:none but it does when I get it to the element as a style instead of as a class. So display:none works but not as a class in this case. When I inspect it in Safari it ignores the CSS and has a "Matched CSS Rules" grey and not editable having div { display: block; }.

Comment: That *is* odd. Do you have an example demonstrating this by any chance? I can't seem to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: Go to the following link in Safari www.bookbay.co.za/App.html you should see the behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching around, I found the culprit:

```
@-moz-keyframes move {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
        opacity: 0.1;
    }; /* This semicolon shouldn't be here */
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
        opacity: 0.1;
    }; /* This semicolon shouldn't be here */
}
```

There shouldn't be semicolons after the animation keyframe percentages. It should be:

```
@-moz-keyframes move {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
        opacity: 0.1;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
        opacity: 0.1;
    }
}
```

I presume that after Safari parses the semicolons, none of the following CSS takes effect.