# Can't toggle between display: contents and display: none in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

Not sure if anyone else has come across this - I am running Safari 12.

I have a very simple setup to demonstrate this bug.

HTML:

```
<div class="contents">
  <p>Hello!</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.contents {
  display: contents;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

See this CodePen: https://codepen.io/ericxgao/pen/dreqWp

If you go to the CodePen, inspect the text and then change the class of the wrapping div from "contents" to "hide", nothing actually happens. In every other browser, the text disappears but in Safari, it doesn't seem to apply. This appears to be a bug documented here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=188259

I'm curious if there's any clever workarounds available here. What's the cleanest way that I can preserve this behavior without overhauling my existing code that uses this toggle?

Comment: Are you ok with using Javascript?

Comment: This item is duplicate. Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142630/safari-not-running-css-displaynone-property?rq=1

Comment: Not a duplicate - that user had an error in their CSS. I have none, and this is a known bug with Safari as I've shown above. I'm seeking alternatives to display: none - this isn't an issue with my code as far as I can tell.

@VapporWashmade I'd prefer to stick with a CSS in a class.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this instead until Safari fixes the issue.

```
.hide * {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```